# Обьясните как работает функция

Tags: c++, функции

```
void SortArr(int arr[], int n) {
    for (int startIndex = 0; startIndex < n - 1; ++startIndex)
    {
        int smallestIndex = startIndex;

        for (int currentIndex = startIndex + 1; currentIndex < n; ++currentIndex)
        {
            if (arr[currentIndex] < arr[smallestIndex])
                smallestIndex = currentIndex;
        }

        swap(arr[startIndex], arr[smallestIndex]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Что именно непонятно?

Comment: [Сортировка выбором](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

хреново она работает :) сложность алгоритма O(n^2)

функция сортировки массива, алгоритм выглядит так:

1. проходим по всем элементам массива от `0` до `n-1`
2. для каждой позиции проходим по всем элементам массива от `i+1` до `n-1`
3. находим минимальное значение элемента в этом диапазоне `[i+1, n-1]`
4. если найденное минимальное значение меньше значения в позиции `i` - меняем их местами

таким образом пройдя полностью на этапе от `0` до `n-1` массив будет отсортирован

Единственное, мне кажется не хватает одной проверки все таки

```
void SortArr(int arr[], int n) {
    for (int startIndex = 0; startIndex < n - 1; ++startIndex)
    {
        int smallestIndex = startIndex;

        for (int currentIndex = startIndex + 1; currentIndex < n; ++currentIndex)
        {
            if (arr[currentIndex] < arr[smallestIndex])
                smallestIndex = currentIndex;
        }

        if (arr[startIndex] < arr[smallestIndex])
            swap(arr[startIndex], arr[smallestIndex]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Это ***сортировка массивов методом выбора***

Объяснение :

1. Аргументы функции : целочисленный массив, размер(потому, что массив не запоминает свою длину при передаче в функцию, в отличии от `std::array` и `std::vector`)
2. `(n - 1)` потому, что последнее сравнение будет самозаменой. Последний элемент уже будет отсортирован к тому времени, когда мы до него дойдем
3. В переменной `smallestIndex` храниться индекс наименьшего значения, которое мы нашли в этой итерации.

Затем ищем элемент поменьше в остальной части массива

4. `startIndex + 1` потому, что отсортированный элемент больше не трогаем
5. Если мы нашли элемент, который меньше `arr[smallestIndex]`,то запоминаем его `smallestIndex = currentIndex;`
6. И, с помощью функции `std::swap()`, меняем местами значения